# How can i set the selected index with data from server to a combobox in a jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, combobox, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a column with a combobox (select), and i set the values in editoptions through a function that returns the required options.

My problems is how can i bring there the values saved:

e.g: my options are : 1:yes,2:no,3:maybe

From the server a client have the option 2 saved and i want to show NO in the jqgrid.

heres a bit of my code:

```
function getAllSelectOptions() {
    var state= {
        '1': 'yes', '2': 'no',
        '3': 'maybe' };
    return state;
}



  function formatTest(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Customers.aspx/getOptions",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(result) {
             //return options.colModel.editoptions.value[result.d]; shows me the value from server, but i cant return it.
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });

    }


//combo
    {
       name: 'column1', index: 'column1', width: 23,

       align: 'center',

       editable: true,

       edittype: 'select',

       formatter: formatTest,

       editoptions: {value: getAllSelectOptions()}

           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't posted enough details about what you do, but I guess that adding `formatter: "select"` to the column should solve the problem. The usage of async call in the formatter is absolutely wrong way. If you set already `editoptions.value` then `formatter: "select"` will uses the information and will decode the input data 1, 2 and 3 to the texts `'yes'`, `'no'` or `'maybe'` which will be displayed in the corresponding column of the grid.

Comment: thanks oleg, i already did that (with some changes )and it worked